# rsync not setting ownership of newly created parent directory when using chown option

Tags: rsync

I want to rsync a sub-directory from one system and place it on a remote host in the same parent directory (that does not exist) on the remote host. If I use rsync as root and specify chown the sub-directory ownership is correct on the remote system but the newly created parent directory is not, the parent directory ends up being root owned. I have to do this as root due to some permission issues that violate ssh security rules (not allowing me to use keys with the target account on the remote host).

Example:

System A:

- bob123:bob123 755 - /home/bob123/configurations/
- bob123:bob123 755 - /home/bob123/configurations/app1/
- bob123:bob123 755 - /home/bob123/configurations/app2/
- ...

System B:

- bob123:bob123 755 - /home/bob123/ **(THIS DIRECTORY IS EMPTY)**

As root on system-A:

```
rsync --chown=bob123:bob123 -IHrlptD /home/bob123/configurations/app4 system-b:/home/bob123/configurations/
```

The result is:

- **root:root** 755 - /home/bob123/configurations
- bob123:bob123 755 - /home/bob123/configurations/app4

I've tried different options but haven't yet found the one that works and `system-b:/home/bob123/configurations` is always root owned while the `app4` directory tree ownership and permissions are correct (owned by bob123:bob123).

If push comes to shove, I could use ssh to run a mkdir, but was wondering if it is possible to use just rsync to do what I want.

Update: Not sure if it matters, but the systems are Ubuntu 18.04 using rsync 3.1.2 and OpenSSH_7.6p1.

**############** **Solution:** **############**

Thank you @roaima for the help!

The `-R` option and `/./` were the missing options. I also had to include the `-go` options as well.

I ended up with something like the following:

```
rsync --chown=bob321:bob321 -IHazR /home/bob123/./configurations/app4 system-b:/home/bob321/
```

If the same user exists on both systems I don't have to use `--chown` but for a remote system with a different process owner in play it is. The above example is making use of chown to reflect the different usage. In my script the chown option setting is dependent on the remote host address.

Again, thank you @roaima for pointing me in the right direction with the `-R` option!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your command (simplified here) does not include `configurations` in the list of directories to be transferred, so the transfer rules such as `chown` do not apply

> ```
> rsync -a /home/bob123/configurations/app4 system-b:/home/bob123/configurations/
> ```

Given that `/home/bob123` already exists on the destination, `rsync` will create a single further directory to match the target `/home/bob123/configurations`. It will then copy the source `app4` file or directory tree into that newly created target directory.

If you want `configurations` to be included in the list of transferred directories you can use the `-R` (`--recursive`) flag and include the source `configurations` directory in the transfer tree

```
rsync --chown=bob123:bob123 -IHrlptDR /home/bob123/./configurations/app4 system-b:/home/bob123/
```

Another way of handling this is to log in as `bob123` on `system-b`, so that everything is implicitly owned by the target user:

```
rsync -Ia /home/bob123/configurations/app4 bob123@system-b:configurations/
```

PS Do you really want `-I` (`--ignore-times`)? Unless you know for certain that you need this flag, do not use it.

Comment: Thank you Roaima for the feedback and examples. I'll give the `-R` option a try. Yes, the `-I` option is needed due to how some of the source files are moved into place and when they were first generated. If the remote image is remastered doing a pull vs a push would be a better option. Regards, Bob.

Comment: `-R` is working _but_ I also had to include the `-go` options. I had stopped using `-a` because I had thought that the `go` options were messing me up. The other key from your example is the use of the `/./` in the source path. I've check the man page again and now understand where I went wrong. I appreciate the help. Thank you!